# Как разбить строку определенным знаком на два разных списка?

Tags: python, строки

т.е например у меня есть строка

```
s = '324,23423423,100000;32432,23,1'
```

можно ли разбить ее на два разных списка знаком ";"(точка с запятой)
и в итоге чтобы получилось

```
s1 = ['324,23423423,100000']
s2 = ['32432,23,1']
```

Comment: @MaxU да, разбивается, но остается в одном списке, а нельзя ли реализовать  чтобы в два разных записывалась каждая часть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте `split(";")`

```
arr = [[el] for el in s.split(";")]
```

если их надо сохранить в переменные `s1` и `s2`, то так:

```
s1, s2 = [[el] for el in s.split(";")]
```

Comment: а если предположим у меня будет больше частей(не две , а 4 к примеру), то нельзя ли каждую часть записывать в сразу же создаваемый список?

Comment: @марат можно...

Answer (score 3):

1. Использовать `exec`:

```
s = '324,23423423,100000;32432,23,1'
for i, val in enumerate(s.split(';')):
    exec(f"s{i} = '{val}'")
```

2. Использовать `globals()`, спасибо [@Danis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/400096/danis) :

```
for i, val in enumerate(s.split(';')):
   globals()[f's{i}'] = val
```

Comment: ещё можно использовать `globals()`

Comment: @Danis, добавил. спасибо за подсказку